# Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'created_at'

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am working in Laravel now. I have created a create_Contacten_table. In which I have made a few columns. But when I try to do a php artisan migrate. It says that the table is a duplicate.

I have tried to do a php artisan:reset and a php artisan:rollback. Both of which did not work. I have deleted the columns and the migration and tried it again. Still no result. I have looked to different questions and answers on StackOverflow. They did not provide a helpful solution. So I thought I might ask it myself.

The error:

Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'created_at' (SQL: create table `_contacten` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null, `naam` varchar(191) not null, `email` varchar(191) not null, `message` mediumtext not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

My create_contacten_php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateContactenTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('_contacten', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string("naam");
            $table->string("email");
            $table->mediumText("message");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('_contacten');
    }
}
```

My AppServiceProvider.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
}
```

I hope that I have provided you guys with enough information so that you can help me find a solution.

Greetings,

Johan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have declared $table->timestamps() two times... Check it carefully

Comment: THANK YOU, I will accept your answer very soon. Salam Alaykom.

Comment: Walaikum assalam and give your vote if you find helpful and others can also find it as helpful..

Answer (score 0):

Great.

I had named attribute twice in my table `$table->string('enquiry') and $table->string('enquiry')`, Which was a big mistake!